# Invalid Object name error in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, asp.net-mvc-2

Just today, out of nowhere I started to get this error;

```
SourceName: ASP.NET 2.0.50727.0

Time: 20110628094209.000000+060

Message: Event code: 3005 Event message:

An unhandled exception has occurred. Event time: 28/06/2011 09:42:09 Event time (UTC): 28/06/2011 08:42:09 Event ID: 8543b22dbcdc4b37a7b456c378c43e71 Event sequence: 2 Event occurrence: 1 Event detail code: 0 Application information:

Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/1001/ROOT-1-129537072751067040 Trust level: Full Application Virtual Path: / Application Path: C:\SomePath Machine name: 227605-WEB2 Process information:

Process ID: 4352 Process name: w3wp.exe Account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE Exception information:

Exception type: SqlException Exception message:

Invalid object name 'SomeTable'. Request information:

Request URL: http://www.somewebsite.com/ Request path: / User host address: 90.152.59.206 User: SomeUser Is authenticated: False Authentication Type: SomeType Thread account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE Thread information:

Thread ID: 6 Thread account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE Is impersonating: False Stack trace: at

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection) at

System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj) at

System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj) at

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.ConsumeMetaData() at

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData() at

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString) at

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async) at

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, DbAsyncResult result) at

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method) at

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method) at

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior) at

System.Data.Common.DbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader() at

NHibernate.AdoNet.AbstractBatcher.ExecuteReader(IDbCommand cmd) at

NHibernate.Loader.Loader.GetResultSet(IDbCommand st, Boolean autoDiscoverTypes, Boolean callable, RowSelection selection, ISessionImplementor session) at

NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoQuery(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters, Boolean returnProxies) at

NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters, Boolean returnProxies) at

NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoList(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters) Custom event details:
```

As far as I could read I ve seen people talking about permissions.
And also we just restarted the server yesterday.
Can it be something we are missing after a restart?

This is our connection string (We are using NHibernate);

```
<property name="connection.connection_string">Database=SomeDatabase;Data Source=SomeDataSource,1433;User ID=SomeUserId;Password=SomePassword;Integrated Security=false;</property>
```

If you need to see anything else please let me know.
Thanks,
Bilsay

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be a simple issue actually. 
In our application we just started to access several databases so in one of our queries we had to start by saying 'Use SomeDatabase;' or adding 'Initial Catalog= SomeDatabase' to our connection string might have worked also.

Anyway, the exception was actually saying whats going on.
It was basically looking at a different database at that moment.
So we ensured that every query executes in the correct database.
Even that NHibernate does the default database thing for you, I m just guessing that using native sql might have complicated the issue.

Bilsay